# Temperature Calculator in React Native

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to develop a basic temp calc and I'm a bit stuck. I've got it somewhat working however, whenever clicking one button they both end up showing results (one of them wrong) and one correct. Also, the both texts and text input change at the same time. Please could help!

Thanks,

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import { TextInput,View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

 export default class App extends React.Component {

 state = {
    celsius: 0,
    fahrenheit: 0,    
}
updateState = () => this.setState ( {

    celsius: (this.state.celsius * 9/5) + 32,
    fahrenheit: (this.state.fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
})   
render() {
    const  { celsius, fahrenheit } = this.state

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <h1> Temperature Converter</h1>

            <TextInput
            value={this.state.celsius}
            onChangeText={ (celsius) => this.setState({ celsius })}
            placeholder={'Celsius Here'}
            style={styles.input}
            />
            <Text style={styles.input}> {celsius} </Text>

            <Button onPress = { () => { this.updateState()}} title="Convert Celsius" />

            <Text>{"\n"}</Text>

            <TextInput
            value={this.state.fahrenheit}
            onChangeText={ (fahrenheit) => this.setState({fahrenheit})}
            placeholder={'Fahrenheit Here'}
            style={styles.input}
            />
            <Text style={styles.input}> {fahrenheit} </Text>

            <Button onPress = { () => {this.updateState()}} title="Convert Fahrenheit" />

          </View>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting issue because

```
updateState = () => this.setState ( {

celsius: (this.state.celsius * 9/5) + 32,
fahrenheit: (this.state.fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
})
```

Your initial celsius and fahrenheit is 0.

And you fill 50  for celsius in your first input.
And you press button then you function call.

it convert celsius into 122.
And  `fahrenheit: (this.state.fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9` this line takes 0 as fahrenheit and calculate to -17.something.
And it change state of your variable. And it keep going on whenever you press the button.

Try after separating both the formula in two different functions.

Try this I have made some changes

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import { TextInput,View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

 state = {
celsius: null,
fahrenheit: null,  
celsius1: null,
fahrenheit1: null,   
}
 updateState = () => this.setState ( {

fahrenheit: (this.state.celsius * 9/5) + 32,
//fahrenheit: (this.state.fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
 })  
 updateState1 = () => this.setState ( {

//celsius: (this.state.celsius * 9/5) + 32,
celsius1: (this.state.fahrenheit1 - 32) * 5 / 9
  })  
 render() {
const  { celsius, fahrenheit, celsius1, fahrenheit1 } = this.state

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

        {/* <h1> Temperature Converter</h1> */}

        <TextInput
        value={this.state.celsius}
        onChangeText={ (celsius) => this.setState({ celsius })}
        placeholder={'Celsius Here'}
        style={styles.input}
        />
        <Text style={styles.input}> {fahrenheit} </Text>

        <Button onPress = { () => { this.updateState()}} title="Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit" />

        <Text>{"\n"}</Text>

        <TextInput
        value={this.state.fahrenheit1} 
        onChangeText={ (fahrenheit1) => this.setState({fahrenheit1})}
        placeholder={'Fahrenheit Here'}
        style={styles.input}
        />
        <Text style={styles.input}> {celsius1} </Text>

        <Button onPress = { () => {this.updateState1()}} title="Convert Fahrenheit to celsius" />

      </View>
)
}
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Okay, I got it working correctly with each button. Now when I convert it changes in the right text input, however I need it to not change there but change in a <text> </text> instead while the text input either goes to 0 or remains the same. Once again tyvm for your help.

Comment: hmm, the one you just posted doesn't work properly for me. Celsius shows up in the fahrenheit text input

Comment: now it will work i forgot to change the value  fahrenheit to fahrenheit1 in second input